# C#: How can I make textarea that accepts only some specific words?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I make a `TextArea` that accepts only the words I have already set
with C# on Visual studio.

I'm a beginner in programming.

---

update:

what (-3) about?
like I said I'm a beginner, trying to build android game with c#.
until now just do some mistakes.

this website little complex to handle with but I will get used to it :) and my english poor

thank you all.

Comment: Your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please add some more detail about your question

Comment: search for regex in c#

Comment: If you looking a solution for web. It's duplicate please check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647404/javascript-function-to-enter-only-alphabets-on-keypress

Comment: @green please elaborate more on your question, please add some sample code on what you have done so far regarding this problem, with that i can be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TextBox and add TextChanged event on your tool

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only alphabetical characters");
        textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

[More Info](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27849/WaterMark-TextBox-For-Desktop-Applications-Using-C)

```
textBox1.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^0-9^+^\-^\/^\*^\(^\)]");
    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(textBox1.Text);
    if (matches.Count > 0) {
       //tell the user
    }
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string yourWord = "mouse";
        if (textBox1_Text.Text.Contains(yourWord))
        {
            textBox1_Text.Text.Replace(yourWord, "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but where should I put my words. example of accepted words: hand, mouse, floor....etc. and unacceptable Inappropriate Words, Spelling mistakes.

Comment: i updated , is it ok?