# how can i allow user to only inputs in alphabet and special char but not integer or number

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried pattern `pattern="[A-Za-z]"` attribute of input type but it allows first and show error at last on form submit 
any example of js,jq will be much helpful and appreciated 
Thanks..

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question will have a better chance of being answered if you provide a [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates what the problem is and what you have tried to fix it. Consider reading the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and updating your question. Cheers :)

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behavior of HTML form validation. If you need a real-time validation, please do some search at SO, there are plenty of examples of real-time validations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Expression you provided must be modified to: ^[A-Za-z -]+$

You can use either from below to match you criteria :

- 0 or more of the preceding expression
- 1 or more of the preceding expression

You can also onchange or onblur add method As ValidateText ex :

```
function lettersOnly() 
{
        var charCode = event.keyCode;

        if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || charCode == 8)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

link : [Javascript Function to enter only alphabets on keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647404/javascript-function-to-enter-only-alphabets-on-keypress?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)